# How to debug in redux react?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am working with React with Redux and getting this error `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'` in console. Nothing is rendering at webpage. 
I don`t know how to find that file or location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use visual studio platform for code, and run code in debugging mode.

Comment: I am using, how start debugging mode ?

Comment: In menubar there is Debug - > start debugging

Comment: Getting this error while debugging :
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:38481/214a410e-86d4-42a8-b193-e06b158129aa
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event      ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 127.0.0.1:7770
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1290:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1338:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1471:7)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:62:10)

Comment: close server connection .

Comment: Go through this : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/introvideos/debugging

Comment: Are you using <script> tag in index.html ? if using then change it to <script type="text/jsx">